# What is the OP asking when the question asks to what a word is pointing?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have seen questions like https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/to-what-is-for-pointing-in-these-sentences where the OP is asking to what a word is pointing. Other questions used *point[ing]* for tenses or verbs.

How can those questions be rephrased not to use *point[ing]*?

Comment: What does "for" referring to in the given sentences?

Comment: @Mohit: What *is* "for" referring to...

Comment: A lot of times when I've read questions phrased this way, the OP means "What is this word describing in this sentence?" That is, asking what something is referring back to, ex: "The house is green, and it is also very big." What does "it" refer to?  (Where the answer would be "the house".) However in this case it seems they're actually asking what the definition of "for" is, so the phrasing doesn't make much sense and isn't the same as the other questions I've seen it used in.